# How to fill a matrix with data with iterated data from a json using forEach?

Tags: javascript

I want to fill a matrix using the push function with iterated data from a json. The error is that the matrix is ​​actually full but I can not access its length or go through the matrix with a for how do I solve this problem?

```
var json = [
     {name: "BPO"},
     {name: "C.I.D."},
     {name: "C.I.D."}
];

const array = [];

json.forEach((item) => { 
 array.push(item.name); 
})
```

Comment: Please show how `json` looks like?

Comment: var json = [
     {name: "BPO"},
     {name: "C.I.D."},
     {name: "C.I.D."}
];